# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple outgoing edges with label: "StreamEntry" for vertex: test2/document1

Tags: java, neo4j, cluster-computing, graph-databases

We have a 3 node neo4j cluster where two nodes acting as front ends are embedded neo4j instances in java with a restlet front end for getting and posting to our graph db.  The 3rd instance is neo4j-enterprise running on ubuntu 13.04 64bit.  All three instances are running on separate VM's.  We're running neo4j 1.9.5.

Everything works well when we eliminate the clustering configuration for neo4j and test against one instance.

When we stress test against the clustered environment, specifically when posting data we quickly run into the following error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple outgoing edges with label: "StreamEntry" for vertex: test2/document1

What would be the cause of this sort of error?

Comment: I managed to clear the error by deleting the document1 node via neo4j's webadmin.  However I would still like to know what the cause of this error might be.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some constraint, that you allow only one relationship with type "StreamEntry" between two nodes?

And you ran into a race condition when creating your data that created more than one of those?